# connecting to atlas mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using node.Js, expressjs mongodb and Atlas

[image]

```
var Db     = require('mongodb').Db;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
```

the above method is not working for me. 
by using atlas database. you are given three nodes with three different host/Url now the problem here is that when I try to connect to **mongodb.server** it only ask for one host name *(or its allowed to add many but I just don't know how)*

my question would be, how can I make this work? like how can I join together 3 different Url and let 1 port let it in. and connect to database server

Comment: Please do not include code in an image, rather paste and format it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

> you are given three nodes with three different host/Url now the problem here is that when I try to connect to mongodb.server it only ask for one host name

[MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) provides you with a [MongoDB Connection URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-uri-format). The connection string should contain host(s) information.

You can also see a snippet example of MongoDB Node.js connecting to MongoDB Atlas on the manual [MongoDB Atlas: Node.js Driver Example](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#node-js-driver-example)

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
   "mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.mongodb.net/");

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("databaseName");
```

MongoDB Version 3.4 and earlier:

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

```
var uri = "mongodb://user:password@mycluster0-shard-00-00.mongodb.net:27017,mycluster0-shard-00-01.mongodb.net:27017,mycluster0-shard-00-02.mongodb.net:27017/admin?ssl=true&replicaSet=Mycluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin";
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
  db.close();
});
```

For other drivers, please see [MongoDB Atlas: Connect via Driver](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#connect-via-driver)